# How to block Tortoise SVN from searching the root branch

Tags: svn, tortoisesvn, branch, root

Since 2 days ago, I cannot connect to a SVN server using Tortoise SVN Client. Here are the details:

[464] #11 Thread:1652 SVNInfo::GetFirstFileInfo(line 136) svn_client_info3 Path=https:// svn.example.com/svn/test1/SUBFOLDER

[464] #11 Thread:1652 done (1703210 µs)

[464] #12 Thread:1652 SVNInfo::GetFirstFileInfo(line 136) svn_client_info3 Path=https:// svn.example.com/svn/test1

[464] #12 Thread:1652 done (1058876 µs)

[464] #13 Thread:1652 SVNInfo::GetFirstFileInfo(line 136) svn_client_info3 Path=https:// svn.example.com/svn

[464] #13 Thread:1652 done (1305293 µs)

[464] #14 Thread:1652 SVNInfo::GetFirstFileInfo(line 136) svn_client_info3 Path=https:// svn.example.com

We have a CRASH at this point.
The messages above were captured using DebugView
We get this error even when using CMD

Error: Unable to connect to a repository at URL
Error:  ‘https://svn.example.com/svn/test1/SUBFOLDER’
Error: Error running context: The server unexpectedly closed the connection.

Any help is more than welcomed!